# PowerApps M:M relationships with additional attributes

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I'm new to PowerApps.  I'm creating a model-driven app.  I've created some custom tables in the DataVerse - Information System, and Business Process.  These tables have a M:M relationship. An Information System supports one or more Business Processes and a Business Process can use one or more Information Systems. I need to capture additional attributes that describe the nature of the relationship - what role does the Information System play with respect to the Business Process, and a score indicating how effective the Information System for that Business Process.

I've learned how to create M:M relationships using the built-in functionality in PowerApps but this does not permit me to define additional attributes for the relationship.

I've created my own M:M "middle" table and created M:1 joins from that table to each of the related tables.  My "middle" table contains a lookup to each of the other tables and the additional attributes I need.

I need to know how to modify the default form for each of the related tables to include the "middle" table to enable a user to select a row from the "other" table and also to supply values for the additional attributes.  I have searched for several days now and have not found any literature explaining how to do this.

I'm hoping there's someone who knows how to do this or can direct me to some literature about how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is right, initially you created a native N:N relationship and for your need it should be manual N:N relationship which you created later.

You can add the subgrid of manual N:N intersect entity (two lookups and extra attributes) in both the main entities - this way you can create related records from either side. It can be a related navigation in the form instead of subgrid as well.

[Read more](https://carldesouza.com/understanding-intersect-entities-and-nn-relationships-in-dynamics-365/)

Comment: Arun;  Thanks for this.  It's exactly what I was looking for.